# Rounding off a formatted string number using JavaScript or ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, string-formatting, extjs4.2

Below, I have a number which I am trying to format using javascript. But it returns NaN.

```
var v = "153,452.47";
alert(Math.round(v));
```

You can use following fiddle: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/webfriend13/nhyNF/)

How can we format a numeric string having separators?

Comment: Remove commas first...

Comment: @elclanrs: I knew thats an option but Í dont want to go that way. Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this will work well

```
var v = "153,452.47";
var float = parseFloat(v.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));
// => 153452.47
```

If you want to round to integer

```
var v = "153,452.47";
float.toFixed(0);
// => 153452
```

Let's make a nice little function!

```
var roundFormattedNumber = function(n){
  var result = parseFloat(n.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));
  return isNaN(result) ? NaN : result.toFixed(0);
};
```

This works more nicely than the other solutions provided, because it's a whitelist regexp replace rather than a blacklist one. That means that it will even work for numbers like `$ 1,234.56`

The other solutions provided will not work for these numbers

```
roundFormattedNumber("$ 123,456,489.00");
//=> 123456789

roundFormattedNumber("999.99 USD");
//=> 1000

roundFormattedNumber("1 000 €");
//=> 1000

roundFormattedNumber("i like bears");
//=> NaN
```

Comment: "This works more nicely than the other solutions provided" That depends; if you want to fail fast on rubbish data you should throw an error so you know where exactly the application is failing. Accepting there might be a comma in the string is different than excepting any string with numbers in it. None of the examples check for NaN though (your function will return when no numbers are in the string) but it would be wise to do so before processing the data further. +1 for a nice complete answer

Comment: @HMR, I've added an explicit NaN return. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the comma.

```
parseFloat("153,452.57".replace(/,/g,"")).toFixed(0);
```

if you want 2 decimals:

```
parseFloat("153,452.57".replace(/,/g,"")).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: what is the difference between them, you wrote same code twice ?

Comment: @pandit I've edited the answer to what I believe HMR meant to say.

Comment: @jcsanyi ya now it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var v = "153,452.47";
Math.round(parseFloat(v.replace(",","")));
```